# Import plain-multidimensional array from TSV-File

Tags: file, powershell, multidimensional-array, csv

How do I import a multi-dimensional array from a tab-separated file?

1. The file has no headers, It may have a blank or a dummy first-line.
2. Should create a simple array and **Not** a HashTable.

TSV file:

> -- empty / irrelevent first-line
>   `"X" "0" "A"`
>   `"Y" "1" "B"`

such that: `array[0][0] = "X"` & `array[1][2] = "B"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$m=gc c:\temp\matrix.txt
$array=@()

$m | Foreach{
    $elements=$_.split("`t")
    $array+= ,@( $elements[0],$elements[1],$elements[2])
}
$array[0][0]
$array[1][2]
```

**note the comma (line 6) that force powershell to consider the added line as an array**

To ignore the first line you can do something like this

```
$matrix=""
(1..($m.count-1)) | foreach{ $matrix+=$m[$_]}
```

Comment: ThankYou! your note about `,` in line:6 is the key.

Comment: if you change `$array+= ,@( $elements[0],$elements[1],$elements[2])
` to `$array += ,$elements` it should work on all elements(not just the three).